# After an attractive non-flash PHP charting solution

Tags: php, html, canvas, charts, svg

I've been using XML/SWF Charts ([maani.us](http://maani.us/)) for ages, but now want to move my charts to a non-flash setup.

On the charts I have at the moment, I have lots of mouseovers, so for instance if you put the mouse over a data point you get a little pop up with more details.

I've recently discovered [pChart](http://www.pchart.net) which looks fantastic, except I don't think that sort of interaction will be possible with it, as they're rendered bitmaps.

Is there something out there that brings together the best of both worlds, using HTML5/SVG/canvas/etc? I don't know much about these newer technologies, but am eager to learn!

This will be a lot of work to port everything over, so I want to make sure I pick the "right" charting solution.

Needs to be:

1. Very customizable
2. Able to generate pretty, appealing graphs that users will want to play with
3. Be interactive.  Tooltip mouseovers at the very least, and possibly more.

Doesn't have to be free, though that's obviously a bonus.  Happy to spend up to $200 say, for the right solution.  The intended use is a commercial website that I own & run.

Many thanks!

edit:
OK, so I have a shortlist now:

- [pChart](http://www.pchart.net) (no dynamic, but very pretty...)
- [Raphael](http://g.raphaeljs.com/)
- [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/)
- [Google charts](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/)
- [amCharts](http://www.amcharts.com/)

Now just need to make sure I pick the "right" one.  Please post below if you know of a good solution that I've not listed!

Comment: Google Chart Tools, maybe? http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/chart/

Answer (score 1):

http://g.raphaeljs.com/

Uses canvas I think.

Edit: The basic Raphael functions should work well too, [example](http://raphaeljs.com/analytics.html)

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [Highcharts](http://www.highcharts.com/) - a javascript charting library.

Answer (score 0):

ExtJS is offered by Sencha in both GPL and commercial licenses.

Chart examples available at: http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/examples/